# Solspace User and/or EE member management on screen messaging

Tags: members, solspace-user

I have a user:edit form so members can update their profile. When user submits the form it redirects to the same page. How would you print a message about the successful submission/update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've often done is this.
/user/edit  returns to /user/edit/success
which is the same page.
Then run a conditional on segment_3 to display your message(s).